# How to prove the equality $ B_n(sx) =s^{n - 1}\sum_{j = 0}^{s - 1} B_n (x + \frac{j}{s}) $

Tags: generating-functions, bernoulli-numbers

Given the following equality:

$$ B_n(sx) =s^{n - 1}\sum_{j = 0}^{s - 1} B_n (x + \frac{j}{s}) $$

where $B_n(x)$ - Bernoulli polynomial

How to prove the equality?

I tried to use generating function, but it has not brought any results. Maybe I choose wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$B_n(qx) = 
q^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{q-1} B_n\left(x+\frac{j}{q}\right).$$

The EGF of the LHS is

$$\frac{t e^{qxt}}{e^t-1}.$$

The EGF of the RHS is

$$q^{n-1} \frac{t e^{xt}}{e^t-1}  
\sum_{j=0}^{q-1} e^{tj/q}
= q^{n-1} \frac{t e^{xt}}{e^t-1} 
\frac{e^t-1}{e^{t/q}-1}
\\ = q^{n-1} \frac{t e^{xt}}{e^{t/q}-1}.$$

The coefficients here are
$$[t^n] q^{n-1} \frac{t e^{xt}}{e^{t/q}-1}
= \frac{1}{q^n} [t^n] 
q^{n-1} \frac{tq e^{qxt}}{e^{t}-1}
= [t^n] \frac{t e^{qxt}}{e^{t}-1}.$$

This is the same as the LHS, done.